# How can I obtain the extracted text from the Azure AI Search when querying .msg email files?

Tags: indexing, indexer, azure-ai-search

I'm trying to access the email body/text that was matched when searching .msg email files that are in an Azure Storage blob container.  I am able get the From, To, Subject and Date Sent using:

metadata_content_type
metadata_message_from
metadata_message_from_email
metadata_message_to
metadata_message_to_email
metadata_message_cc
metadata_message_cc_email
metadata_message_bcc
metadata_message_bcc_email
metadata_creation_date
metadata_last_modified
metadata_subject

Documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-blob-metadata-properties

How can I retrieve the body and attachment text that was matched?

Are there additional fields I can add to my index and/or indexer?

I have tried the following fields:

```
{
    "name": "email-msg-index",  
    "fields": [
        {"name": "ID", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": false},
        {"name": "metadata_subject", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false},
        {"name": "metadata_content_type", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false},
        {"name": "metadata_message_from", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false},
        {"name": "metadata_message_from_email", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false},
        {"name": "metadata_message_to", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false},
        {"name": "metadata_message_to_email", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false},
        {"name": "metadata_message_cc", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false},
        {"name": "metadata_message_cc_email", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false},
        {"name": "metadata_message_bcc", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false},
        {"name": "metadata_message_bcc_email", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false},
        {"name": "metadata_creation_date", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false},
        {"name": "metadata_last_modified", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to obtain the content using the following index: `{ "name": "email-msg-index",   "fields": [ {"name": "ID", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": false}, {"name": "metadata_subject", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false}, {"name": "metadata_content_type", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false}, {"name": "metadata_message_from", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false}, {"name": "metadata_message_from_email", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false}, {"name": "metadata_message_to", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false}, {"name": "metadata_message_to_email", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false}, {"name": "metadata_message_cc", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false}, {"name": "metadata_message_cc_email", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false}, {"name": "metadata_message_bcc", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false}, {"name": "metadata_message_bcc_email", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false}, {"name": "metadata_creation_date", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false}, {"name": "metadata_last_modified", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false}, {"name": "content", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false} ] }`

The indexer used is: `{ "@odata.context": "https://<servicename>.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity", "@odata.etag": "\"0x000000000000000\"", "name": "emailindexer", "dataSourceName": "email-blob-datasource", "targetIndexName": "email-msg-index", "parameters": { "configuration": { "indexedFileNameExtensions": ".msg", "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata", "parsingMode": "default" } } }`

The query is:
{
"search": "{{search}}",
"select": "metadata_subject, metadata_creation_date, metadata_message_from, metadata_message_to, content",
"searchFields": "metadata_subject",
"count": true
}